# Carpet washer keeps tripping main switch

Tags: electrical, circuit-breaker

I have this carpet washer you can see in the picture which keeps tripping my main switch.
The 1st time I used it all worked fine, now I can only use it for 30 seconds and then the main switch trips. I did try to use different sockets in the house and I have the same problem no matter which socket it is plugged in to.
Any suggestion will be much appreciated.
Thank you

[image]

Comment: Does your "main switch" have a TEST button on it that trips it?

Answer (score 5):

Certainly sounds like you are in an area with a [RCBO](https://uk.rs-online.com/web/generalDisplay.html?id=ideas-and-advice/rcbo-guide) on the main switch and the carpet washer has a >30ma ground fault, since there's no conceivable way that the cord to that device could carry enough current to trip the main on overcurrent more than once (the cord would be slag before the second time.) *Given the UK-style plug visible, that matches the normal power setup I'm familiar with there from visiting.*

The carpet washer needs to be serviced to correct the fault (conceivable, but rare these days) or replaced.

Comment: Thanks for saying it for me.  The carpet washer is drawing too much electricity.  This is typical when the motor is seeing too much back resistance (meaning bearings or belts need maintenance) or the motor's windings are slightly damaged (due to abrasion by dust) or some other means.   Effectively you have a motor that already uses a lot of power doing double-duty as an even less efficient motor and a heater.  The breaker is cutting out the circuit before that heat hits something critical, requiring a fire extinguisher.